# Interact with Pythons' Calendar module

Tags: python, module, calendar, interaction

Basically, by using

```
text_cal = calendar.TextCalendar(firstweekday = 0)
# printing formatmonth
cal = text_cal.formatmonth(correct_year, correct_month, 5)

print(cal)
```

which produces this

```
               January 2023                                                                                                                                                                            
 Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat   Sun                                                                                                                                                               
                                       1                                                                                                                                                               
   2     3     4     5     6     7     8                                                                                                                                                               
   9    10    11    12    13    14    15                                                                                                                                                               
  16    17    18    19    20    21    22                                                                                                                                                               
  23    24    25    26    27    28    29                                                                                                                                                               
  30    31
```

I would like to know how can I interact with it meaning for example to assign an * next to a number if I have a specific event booked for that specific day.  The data regarding the events comes from a `.csv` file so to my understanding after making the necessary computations, I should edit the calendar and append an * to that date. The thing is that I do not know how to do this. Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since `cal` is a string, you can manipulate the string however you want.
For instance, you can use regex to find a particular date, e.g. `23` and replace with a modified date, e.g. `23*`.
Here is a function that might help you:

```
import re
def edit_dates(cal_str: str, date_str: str ) -> str: 
  """
  Takes a calendar as string, a date that will be modified as string; 
  Returns a modified calendar as string using regex
  """
  return re.sub(f'(?<!\d){date_str}(?!\d)', f'{date_str}*', cal_str)
```

To call the function:

```
edit_dates(cal, '23')
```

You can then loop through the dates in your CSV using this function. I hope this helps.